# how can i delete the list tag : StaxEventItemWriter

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch, xstream

I want to generate XML file using Spring Batch (StaxEventItemWriter), but I stuck on below problem for 1 week.

Expected xml :

```
<RattPourUneReference>
    <DonneesPrestations>
        <Operation CdIdcDblRat="4" DtOuvDrt="1961-01-01">
        </Operation>
    </DonneesPrestations>

    <DonneesPrestations>
        <Operation CdIdcDblRat="4" DtOuvDrt="1961-01-01">
        </Operation>
    </DonneesPrestations>
</RattPourUneReference>
```

But i got :

```
<RattPourUneReference>
    <list>
    <DonneesPrestations>
        <Operation CdIdcDblRat="4" DtOuvDrt="1961-01-01">
        </Operation>
    </DonneesPrestations>

    <DonneesPrestations>
        <Operation CdIdcDblRat="4" DtOuvDrt="1961-01-01">
        </Operation>
    </DonneesPrestations>
    </list>
</RattPourUneReference>
```

how can i remove the list tag : `<list> </list>`?

Below is the source code of my java class :

```
public class RattPourUneReference {


    private List<DonneesPrestations> list;

    public void setList(List<DonneesPrestations> list) {
        list= list;
    }

    public List<DonneesPrestations> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try given below code:

```
public class RattPourUneReference {

private List<DonneesPrestations> donneesPrestations;

  public void setDonneesPrestations(List<DonneesPrestations> donneesPrestationsList) {
      this.donneesPrestations= donneesPrestationsList;
  }

  public List<DonneesPrestations> getDonneesPrestations() {
      return donneesPrestations;
  }
}
```